# Do I have to GFCI protect a range plug if it's within 6 feet of a sink?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a range plug within 6 feet of a sink, do I need a GFCI?

I do not have a 2014 NEC code book so I don't know if the code has changed. It has not been required in the past but things can change.

Comment: Are you installing a NEMA 10 (3 prong) or a NEMA 14 (4 prong)?

Comment: A 4 wire NEMA 14. thanks, since it is a new install I will go ahead and install a 4 wire plug.  I can wire anything the customer buys.

Answer (score 4):

No in any case.

Electric range circuits and receptacles do not require GFI protection, and if this is a regular receptacle for a gas range it is behind the range and not serving the counter, so again ,no GFI required.

Comment: I thought so but it never hurts to be sure,. I will use a portion of the profits to buy a 2014 code book so I wont have to ask stuff I should know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

While GFCI protection isn't at all required on a 50A electric stove circuit -- it is only required on 15 and 20A receptacles serving kitchen counters as per 210.8(A):

> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere 
>   receptacles installed in the locations specified in 21O.8(A)(1) through (10) 
>   shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for personnel.
>
> (6) Kitchens - where the receptacles are installed to serve the countertop 
>   surfaces

you *can* install ground-fault protection on the range circuit using a two-pole GFCI breaker if you wish, since you are running a separate ground wire to the appliance -- nothing in Code prohibits it, and it can protect your oven from damage caused by element-to-ground arc fault failures.

Note that this *doesn't* work if you don't have a ground wire run (i.e. you're putting a NEMA 10 outlet in) -- this is because of the exception to 250.140:

> *Exception: For existing branch-circuit installations only where an equipment 
>   grounding conductor is not present in the outlet or junction box, the frames 
>   of electric ranges, wall-mounted ovens, counter-mounted cooking units, clothes 
>   dryers, and outlet or junction boxes that are part of the circuit for these 
>   appliances shall be permitted to be connected to the grounded circuit 
>   conductor if all the following conditions are met.*
>
> *(1) The supply circuit is 120/240-volt, single-phase, 3-wire; or 208Y/120-
>   volt derived from a 3-phase, 4-wire, wye-connected system.*
>
> *(2) The grounded conductor is not smaller than 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG
>   aluminum.*
>
> *(3) The grounded conductor is insulated, or the grounded conductor is 
>   uninsulated and part of a Type SE service-entrance cable and the branch 
>   circuit originates at the service equipment.*
>
> *(4) Grounding contacts of receptacles furnished as part of the equipment are 
>   bonded to the equipment.*

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on which code your local authority having jurisdiction is following. The 2017 code requires ALL outlets in living spaces (except for bathrooms) be AFCI protected. If it is within 6 feet of the sink it must also be GFCI protected even if the receptacle is located behind the range. Same thing with the small appliance, range hood, microwave, dishwasher, garbage disposal, refrigerator and other kitchen circuits. In addition cord connected dishwasher and microwave/range hood receptacles can no longer be located behind the appliance.

Comment: This is only true for 15/20A, 120V receptacles.  There is no suitable AFCI for the OP's electric range receptacle...